# Why JavaScript Compressors replace single quotes with double quotes?

Tags: javascript, quotes, minify

Making some Bookmarklet, I tried to use JavaScript minifier like [Google Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) or [YUI Compressor](http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/). However, I didn't use these because they replace every single quotes with double quotes. I can't use a code which has double quotes, as I should enclose the code with double quotes like:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('hello')">hello</a>
```

So, I used [MinifyJavascript](http://www.minifyjavascript.com/) for minifying. I wonder why other minifiers replace quotes. Replacing quotes doesn't minify codes. Coding style is not important for minified code. Then what is the reason for this?

Comment: That's a line of HTML, not JavaScript.  In plain JavaScript, it's always possible to escape embedded quotes with a backslash.

Comment: That's a example code of Bookmarklet. In the example, the code I want to minify is `alert('hello')`, and Minifiers make it to `alert("hello")`.

Comment: In that case, can't you simply do `<a href='javascript:alert("hello")'>`?

Comment: @StephenChung That's right!:)

Comment: (For future readers) Since you talk about Google Closure.. That compiler does *not* blindly replace single quotes with double quotes; instead it chooses an *optimal* (for minifying) *quotation character* and defaults to double quotes when both single and double quotes 'compile' to the same length string. Since +/- 30 Oct 2012, there is an option to *change the default quoting character* from double quote to single quote with the cli-switch: `--formatting SINGLE_QUOTES`. For further info, read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19874863/588079).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure speculation in this answer:

- Enforce style consistency.
- Consistency reduces size when gzip'ed, because of repeating character sequences.

Can't really think of anything else.
They could have chosen single quotes instead of double, though.

Comment: Probably for better compression.

Comment: Well, whatever the reason, it breaks my bookmarklet.